# Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Javascript to display a div when text in the texbox is changed. This is using bootstrap framework. But I cant seem to get it to work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("auto");
  if (this.value==" " || this.value=="") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    ele.innerHTML = "chuckbeyor101@hotmail.com<br>josh@computersbyjd.com";
    ele.style.display = "block";
  }  
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Customer Information</b>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="email" onkeyup="myFunction()">
    <div style="display: none" id="auto">
      Test Div
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here, and why the jQuery tag? Post the rendered HTML. Also, have you tried debugging the code? What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: @Oriol I don't recommend that you fix the OPs code in an edit. The problem then becomes unclear. Please post an answer instead.

Comment: @showdev I didn't fix the code. I just got rid of irrelevant PHP, separated html and js, and improved formatting.

Comment: @Oriol My mistake. I incorrectly assumed that part of the problem was the location of the javascript function (function not found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside `myFunction`, `this` is no longer `event.currentTarget`. Instead, it will be `window` in non-strict mode, or `undefined` in strict mode.

You could fix that setting the value of `this` manually, e.g. using `call`:

```
onkeyup="myFunction.call(this)"
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("auto");
  if (this.value==" " || this.value=="") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    ele.innerHTML = "chuckbeyor101@hotmail.com<br>josh@computersbyjd.com";
    ele.style.display = "block";
  }  
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Customer Information</b>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="email" onkeyup="myFunction.call(this)">
    <div style="display: none" id="auto">
      Test Div
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But better use `addEventListener` and get rid of inline event handlers:

```js
document.getElementsByName('email')[0].addEventListener('input', function() {
    // Your code here.
});
```

Note I used `input` event because inputs can be changed in other ways than the keyboard.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("auto");
document.getElementsByName('email')[0].addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (!this.value.trim()) {
    ele.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    ele.innerHTML = "chuckbeyor101@hotmail.com<br>josh@computersbyjd.com";
    ele.style.display = "block";
  }  
});
```

```css
#auto {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Customer Information</b>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <div id="auto">
      Test Div
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I like your answers, they work in the snippets, but not in my site. Does it have to do with me using boot strap or that my pages are .php?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` points to global object when event handler is called like in your code. You can pass input element object into function to be able to read `value` property:

```
<input type="text" name="email" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
```

and javascript:

```
function myFunction(obj) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("auto");
    if (obj.value == " " || obj.value == "") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        ele.innerHTML = "<?php echo $clients?>";
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the this, and avoid insert JavaScript in your html you should use event listener

```
    var ele = document.getElementById("auto");
    document.getElementById('keyup').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      if (this.value.trim()) {
        ele.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        ele.text = "<?php echo $clients?>";
        ele.style.display = "block";
      } 
    });
```

html:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="keyup">
<div style="display: block" id="auto">Test Div</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you were missing "text" property after in the if else conditional statement. Try that and see if the issue still exist.